# UIToolbar as Subview into another UIViewController is not clickable

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I am creating an app with multiple `UIViewController`, they have common menu and toolbar in header. i have created a uiviewcontroller with nib for top `UIToolBar` with some `UIToolBarButtons`. I am calling in another `UIViewController`, my problem is this that `UIToolBar` is displaying but any of `UIToolbar` button is not clickable now, they are not working. so it only showing the view which is not working at all.

Comment: Please see UIView UserInterfaceEnabled or not..

Comment: Thanks for reply.but its enabled. when i call my my uitoolbar view directly its working but calling it as subview is not working.

Comment: i can't understand what exactly are you want to do ?

Comment: i want to use a common uitoolbar in multiple uiviewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

Please see UIView UserInterfaceEnabled or not. if not then just write below code in your viewdidload

```
        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

OR also try this

```
            [self.view bringSubviewToFront:youtoolbar];
```

Answer (score 0):

just try this code something skip you from your code

```
[yourBarButton setTarget:self];
[yourBarButton setAction:@selector(yourBtnClicked:)];

[yourToolBar setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:yourToolBar];
```

**UPDATE:**

For use this `UIToolBar` to every `UIViewController`, just add it in window and set method in AppDelegate class also...

hope this help you...

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i have created a independent uiviewcontroller with a nib that already contain all the objects and function, my problem is this that i cant reuse my code, i have to write it in all my controllers.

Comment: yes ,in your viewControllers .m file just write above code and then test it , it working or not..

Comment: @user1912480 hey for your this requirement add UIToolBar in window for use it to every UIViewController

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. You remove your toolbar in viewWillAppear and add it again like

```
(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
 {
     [yourtoolbar_reference removeFromSuperview];
     [self.view addSubview:yourtoolbar_reference];
  }
```